Can DT and Crosstalk dynamically link two tables?
I want to link two tables, so that selections in one appear in the other. For example, can selecting a row in one table subset the other table? In my reprex, the two tables work independently. How can I link them?
library(crosstalk)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame("text"= c("a","b","c"),
                 "number"= c(1:3))

shared_data <- SharedData$new(df, key = ~id)


shared_data %>% DT::datatable()
shared_data %>% DT::datatable()




This best I could do is using a filter to edit both tables
filter_checkbox("selection", "test", shared_data, ~df$text, inline = TRUE)

